# How do I upload multiple images into a gallery for a small website without adding lag?

Tags: html, png

If I just add 20 images or so, the site takes too long to load. 
How can I make my site load as quickly as Google images and look 
more or less like it but with at most 20 images (similar size 
as Google images are)? Is it possible?

Here is an example page that takes too long to load:
http://dougingramnursery.com/whats-new/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you might want to show us some code if you have some, we could help optimize it a bit. Then make sure you place your scripts when possible at the bottom of the body. Also compress the images using an image compressor along with using .htaccess to leverage browser caching. Which will practically remember those pictures when the users visits the page again, which will speed things up. Try to combine multiple CSS and JS files together or compress them using a tool such as [Smaller](http://smallerapp.com/) if you have a Mac. If you're using Amazon S3 for hosting your images it should usually be pretty fast. But if its on your site then it might be a bit slower. SSL also slows down the time a bit. Your best bet would be to take a speed test and figure out whats causing the lag. Here's a few websites that will help with that.

1. [Pingdom Website Speed Test](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/)
2. [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)
3. [GTMetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/)

Comment: Running the speed test your images are defiantly large. Consider compressing them.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Yahoo's SmushIt service to optimize your photos > http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/. After optimizing your photos re-upload them to the site, this should improve load time. Let me know if this helps.

- Jesse

Comment: The OP is using a CMS. Hence the wp-content http://dougingramnursery.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/frog.jpg

Comment: Ah nice catch, didn't see that.

Comment: Plus the images are way to big to be fit for thumbnails. So compressing or resizing is good. :) http://dougingramnursery.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/cuph.jpg

Comment: Agreed! They're massive! Ha ha. :D

Answer (score 0):

The images are definitely larger than google images, google images shows you thumbnails then when you click it it shows you the larger image.

To create a thumbnail you can scale it down with any image editor.

Comment: This is an important suggestion. By making downscaled thumbnails you can speed up the image download 100x while by improving the compression you'll only gain another 30 percent or so.  Don't rely on the HTML width and height values to scale an image down in the browser after downloading the whole huge images.  You can optimize the images as others have suggested but that's only good after you have taken care of the scaling.